# Is correct the function of Delphi XE-8 below?

Tags: delphi, utf-8

```
function Trim_emo(SL: TStringList): TStringList;
var
  I:Integer;
  S:string;
begin
  Result := TStringList.Create;
  if (SL.Text='') then
  begin
    Exit;
  end;
  try
    Result.Clear;
    for I := 0 to SL.Count-1 do
    begin
      S := SL[I];
      S := Trim(S);
      if (S<>'') then
        Result.Add(ANSIUpperCase(S));
    end;
  except
    on E : exception do
      ShowMessage(E.Message);
  end;
end;
```

Will this function work fine when StringList contains UTF-8 Characters?

Comment: What about freeing the result ?

Comment: @RepeatUntil That's the caller's responsibility

Comment: Did it work fine when you *tested* it with UTF-8 characters?

Comment: This seems to be something you could test yourself in less time than it took you to come here and post your question. Is there a reason you didn't just do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will never have to deal with UTF-8 characters because it will never encounter them. Delphi strings are UTF-16 encoded. If you wonder how the code will work with Unicode input then there's no problem. UTF-16 is a full Unicode encoding.

There are a couple of problems with your code:

- If an exception is raised, the code will leak a string list instance.
- Your exception handling is broken. If an exception is raised and handled, then an error message is shown. However, the execution continues as if nothing happened. Simply remove the exception handling and let the exception float upwards.
- It is wasteful to evaluate `Text` just to check if the input is empty. If the input is not empty you could create a very long string which you immediately throw away. This test is simply needless and can be removed.

This would be better:

```
function  Trim_emo(SL: TStringList): TStringList;
var  
  I: Integer; 
  S: string;
begin 
  Result := TStringList.Create; 
  try
    for I := 0 to SL.Count-1 do
    begin
      S := Trim(ANSIUpperCase(SL[I]));      
      if S<>'' then
        Result.Add(S);
    end;
  except
    Result.Free;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```